# MongoDB find with Convert field type

Tags: c#, mongodb

Query Mysql can do:

```
SELECT CONVERT('123' USING UNSIGNED) from xTable where CONVERT('123' USING UNSIGNED)=123;
```

MongoDB find can do that ? i want convert string field type to tojsonObject() with criteria find native query.

Comment: MongoDB cannot "cast" the result back, but is is possible to "test" using [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/). However that is bad practice as the necessary JavaScript evaluation is both inherrently slower nor can use an index to filter results. The same could be said of the compared SQL. If you intend a numeric value, then it is better to convert the data to be numeric in storage.

Comment: hi Blake, Thanks for your advice :)